# Private accessible vs Public

Tags: c#, encapsulation

I have problems with the encapsulation, and I don't where the problem is. Why can the line be altered after it has been created? This tells me something is wrong in my "line-class" and needs to be encapsulated. Advise would be much appreciated.
When calling "`pa.X = 4`" and "`startpos.Y = 7`" this should not change the line for me, but it does. I expect that all the lines are unchanged when the program has finished.

Dotclass:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Dot
{
    class Dot
    {
        private int x;
        private int y;

        public Dot()
        {
            this.X = 0;
            this.Y = 0;

        }
        public Dot(int x, int y)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y; 
        }

        public int X
        {
            get
            { return x; }
            set { x = value; }
        }

        public int Y
        {
            get { return y; }
            set { y = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Lineclass:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Dot
{
    class Line
    {
        private Dot startdot;
        private Dot enddot;
        private double length;

        public Line(Dot pa, Dot pb)
        {
            this.startdot = pa;
            this.enddot = pb;            
        }

        public double Size()
        {
            double a = (double)(enddot.X - startdot.X); 
            double b = (double)(enddot.Y - startdot.Y);

            return length = Math.Sqrt(a * a + b * b);            
        }

        public Dot Position()
        {
            return startdot;
        }

    }
}
```

Main:

```
    using System;
    namespace Dot
    {
        class Program
        {
            public static void Main()
            {
                Dot pa = new Dot();
                Dot pb = new Dot(-10, -10);
                Console.WriteLine("Dot pa, position = (" + pa.X + ", " + pa.Y + ")");
                Console.WriteLine("Dot pb, position = (" + pb.X + ", " + pb.Y + ")");
                Line line = new Line(pa, pb);
                Print("Run 1 off line", line);
                pa.X = 4;
                Print("Run 2 off line", line);
                Dot startpos = line.Position();
                startpos.Y = 7;
                Print("Run 3 off line", line);
            }
            private static void print(string text, Line line)
            {
                double length = line.Size();
                Dot startPos = line.Position();
                Console.WriteLine("\n" + text);
                Console.WriteLine("Längd = {0 :f4} length", length);
                Console.WriteLine("Position = ({0},{1})", startPos.X, startPos.Y);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that the `Dot` class is mutable. Does it *have* to be? If not, simply make the `set` of `X` and `Y` private. If for whatever reason `Dot` *must* be mutable, you could let `Line` work with a "clone". For example: `public Line(Dot pa, Dot pb) { startdot = new Dot(pa.X, pa.Y); enddot = new Dot(pb.X, pb.Y); }`

Comment: I tried replacing my Line constructor with this one, but value changes

Comment: It is because your `set` of X is public. Even your data menber is private, but you provide a public way for other to change the private x.

Comment: I think your problem is deep copying vs shadow copying.

Comment: Change `public Dot Position()` to `return new Dot(startdot.X, startdot.Y);` -- but maybe your concept of what a dot is is wrong. Why does it have to be mutable? A dot is a dot. It doesn't "move". You don't take the origin (0,0) and move it to become (4,0) for example. (4,0) is another different dot. The *variable* `pa` might at one point be a reference to (0,0) and at some other point be a reference to (4,0). But that doesn't mean that the *value* (0,0) was changed. Like in `int x = 0; x = 4;` you don't change the *value* `0` to suddenly be the *value* `4`.

Comment: You could have a method like `public Dot SetX(double x) { return new Dot(x, this.Y); }` in `Dot` and use it like `pa = pa.SetX(4);`. It's a little bit more cumbersome than just `pa.X = 4;`, but now you can make `Dot` completely immutable (you probably want a `SetX` and maybe even a `SetXY`, too). And immutability is *a good thing*. See Eric Lipperts [articles](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/tag/immutability/) about it for more info.

Answer (score 4):

> Why can the line be altered after it has been created?

The reason is that `class Dot` is a *reference* type, and you want a *value* type, `struct`:

```
  // please, notice "struct"
  public struct Dot {
    // you don't need separate fields, but properties
    public int X {get; set;}
    public int Y {get; set;}

    public Dot(int x, int y) { 
      X = x;
      Y = y;
    }
  }

  ....
```

**EDIT:** I suggest turning `public Dot Position()` into *property* as well:

```
 class Line {
   ...
   public Dot Position {
     get {
       return startdot;
     }
     set {
       startdot = value;
     }
   } 
 }
```

and so you can "control the angles":

```
line.Position = new Dot(line.Position.X, 5);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however Dot needs to be mutable

Comment: @iscilcra: `Dot` is mutable,  `Dot d = new Dot(1, 2); d.X = 123; d.Y = 456;`

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for seeming demanding, but it supposed to be a class and the changes are meant to be made on the Lineclass. I want to control all angles.

Comment: @iscilcra: it seems, that you have to change `public Dot Position()` into *property* for that (see my edit)